# XNA Camera Class Not Working

Tags: c#, xna, camera, rotation

So I'm making a game with a camera, which works similarly like the sims 2 camera.
What I want to accomplish is a camera which can:

Roatate around the focus point.

Provides the three necessary matrices (World, View and Proj), and the world and view matrices are recalculated each frames.

When the Position vector changes, let's say the X part of it, it should move left/right, not along the X axis, if you know what I mean.

A relative focus vector.

However, I have problems with the moving left/right-part. I'll give you the code that I have. Note that in this version of the code, I haven't tried to implement it yet.

```cs
private float worldRotation = 0;
public void RotateAroundFocusPoint(float relativeDegrees)
{
    worldRotation += MathHelper.ToRadians(relativeDegrees);
}

public Matrix World, View, Proj;
public Vector3 Position, Focus /*relative*/;

public void Update()
{
    World = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-Position - Focus) *
        Matrix.CreateRotationY(worldRotation);
    View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(-Focus, Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
}
```

I'm kind of a noob when it comes to 3d programming, so I hope you can help me out!

Thanks in advance,

Antonie

Comment: @JWiley Haha, well I have several times, but they've all failed! I don't see the point of posting a failed try,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out myself. It is a bit of a workaround, but I implemented it using the following methods:

```cs
private float worldRotation = 0;
public void RevolveAroundFocusPoint(float relativeDegrees)
{
    worldRotation += MathHelper.ToRadians(relativeDegrees);
}

public Vector3 Modified
{
    get
    {
        Vector3 f = Vector3.Transform(Focus, Matrix.Invert(Matrix.CreateRotationY(worldRotation)));
        return new Vector3(f.X, Position.Y, f.Z);
    }
}
public float Multiplier(float value, Vector3 v3)
{
    return value / /*Zoom / */ (Math.Abs(v3.X) + Math.Abs(v3.Z));
}
public void MoveRight(float value)
{
    Vector3 f = Modified;
    float multiplier = Multiplier(value, f);
    Position += new Vector3(f.Z * multiplier, 0, f.X * multiplier);
}
public void MoveLeft(float value)
{
    Vector3 f = Modified;
    float multiplier = Multiplier(value, f);
    Position += new Vector3(-f.Z * multiplier, 0, -f.X * multiplier);
}
public void MoveBackward(float value)
{
    Vector3 f = Modified;
    float multiplier = Multiplier(value, f);
    Position += new Vector3(-f.X * multiplier, 0, f.Z * multiplier);
}
public void MoveForward(float value)
{
    Vector3 f = Modified;
    float multiplier = Multiplier(value, f);
    Position += new Vector3(f.X * multiplier, 0, -f.Z * multiplier);
}

public Matrix World;
public Matrix View;
public Matrix Proj;

public Vector3 Position { get; private set; }
public Vector3 Focus;

public void Update()
{
    World = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-Position - Focus) *
        Matrix.Invert(Matrix.CreateRotationY(worldRotation)) *
        Matrix.CreateScale(Zoom) *
        Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position + Focus);
    View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(Position, Position + Focus, Vector3.Up);
}
```